# Big O notation, why can we "cut" to lower exponents terms?

Tags: calculus

I came with this doubt, for example here's the Taylor series for the exponential function:

https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/23fb781eeb1ebfc91d8eb0124b8b7998d2a13711

Why can we cut to lower exponents? Is it right to say $O(x^2)+O(x^3)=O(x^2)$?
I understand perfectly that this is an abuse of notation.

Comment: We can't really help without some context. Do you know the definition of the notation $O(x^2)$?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation I'm using the definition here in Wikipedia so $g(x)\in O(x^2)$ iff $|g(x)|<M x^2$ for some fixed $M\in\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Great start! The link in your post adds the condition $x\to0$, so: $g(x)\in O(x^2)$ as $x\to0$ if and only if $|g(x)| < Mx^2$ in a neighborhood of $x=0$ for some fixed $M\in\Bbb R$. Now: can you prove, using this definition, that $\frac{x^2}2+\frac{x^3}6 = O(x^2)$ as $x\to 0$? Can you prove that $\frac{x^2}2+O(x^3) = O(x^2)$ as $x\to 0$?